# if(command.permissions.length){ ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')

Tags: node.js, discord

Please help. Whenever I type a command that's not set to anything it gives me an error and shuts down the bot. Is there anyway I can make it catch the error?

Here is the full error message:

```
PS C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot> node . 
Minecraft PVP Tierlist is now online!
C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\events\guild\message.js:45
      if(command.permissions.length){
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')
    at module.exports (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\events\guild\message.js:45:18)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1068:20)
PS C:\Users\brady\Desktop\DiscordBot>
```

```
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

    const validPermissions = [
        "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE",
        "KICK_MEMBERS",
        "BAN_MEMBERS",
        "ADMINISTRATOR",
        "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
        "MANAGE_GUILD",
        "ADD_REACTIONS",
        "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
        "PRIORITY_SPEAKER",
        "STREAM",
        "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        "SEND_MESSAGES",
        "SEND_TTS_MESSAGES",
        "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
        "EMBED_LINKS",
        "ATTACH_FILES",
        "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
        "MENTION_EVERYONE",
        "USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS",
        "VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS",
        "CONNECT",
        "SPEAK",
        "MUTE_MEMBERS",
        "DEAFEN_MEMBERS",
        "MOVE_MEMBERS",
        "USE_VAD",
        "CHANGE_NICKNAME",
        "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
        "MANAGE_ROLES",
        "MANAGE_WEBHOOKS",
        "MANAGE_EMOJIS",
      ]
    
      if(command.permissions.length){
        let invalidPerms = []
        for(const perm of command.permissions){
          if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
            return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
          }
          if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
            invalidPerms.push(perm);
          }
        }
        if (invalidPerms.length){
          return message.channel.send(`You do not have permission to do`);
        }
      }
    
    
    
    if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
    }
```

Comment: *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')* - It seems like your `command.permissions` may be giving some issues, perhaps `command` is not what you expect it to be and permissions is null?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 the error is pretty clear, `command` is `undefined` and thus one cannot access `command.permissions`. OP should check what `cmd` is what he expects it to be (probably not). And if yes, if `client.commands` contains this `cmd` so it could return a value (obviously not)

Comment: "*Is there anyway I can make it catch the error*" Of course there is. Check if `command` has a valid value before accessing any of its properties

Comment: @derpirscher It is clear, which is why I suggested they check their command value. It can seem condescending to point out that they simply failed to read, so I try to word it in a nicer way to prompt them to investigate on their own.

Comment: Also to further @derpirscher point on checking the command value. You could also implement a [try-catch](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-is-try-catch/) to try some code and *catch* an error if it messes up. That is pretty ubiquitous throughout different programming languages so you should be able to find a lot of tutorials and information on what a `try-catch` statement is.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the bot from shutting down on an error you can insert this code at the top of the file:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", console.error); // prevent exit on error
```